# Effectively using the Decorator pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, decorator

I am designing a library that provides access to the Bug Tracker application our company uses.

For the time being, we simply need access to simple functions:

1. Open Defect
2. Query defect (search by given criteria)
3. Connect/Disconnect from Bug Tracker

I designed the library to provide an interface with these operations, so that we could transparently replace implementations when a new version comes out.

In order to support more operations in the future we could:

1. Expand the interface; Make all implementing classes implement the added members.
2. Use the Decorator pattern to add operations/functionality at runtime.

The problem is -- Decorator seems to be too tied to the underlying base class/interface.
What i mean is, it relies on the fact that the object it decorates provides enough access to let it add operations easily.

In this example, if i do NOT expose the underlying 3rd party object providing the API for the bug tracker in my interface, a decorator will not be able to add more operations.

How can i overcome this issue by designing it better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You don't need the Decorator pattern

The decorator pattern isn't very useful for this scenario.  Its purpose is to allow you to append behaviors *at runtime*.  You're trying to append behavior (more or less) *at compile time*.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

This pattern allows the user to create these types of instances of your code:

- Intentionally undecorated types, that only have the base behavior
- Arbitrarily decorated types that allow you to provide overridden behavior

To do this, it incurs a lot of design overhead.  For only one decoration, you need to implement four classes.

This is a lot of overhead if you don't care about instantiating intentionally undecorated types.

### You might not need to worry about this at all

I would only worry about this scenario if you've already rolled out an interface, and it would be costly to redeploy everything at once (clients and services).  If you have the luxury of redeploying the entire world at once, for all users, just modify the interface instead.

### Multiple interfaces are a better match for your scenario

If you simply want to keep your services and clients running while doing a staggered rollout, I'd recommend you take advantage of the fact that .Net allows multiple inheritance for interfaces, and version your interfaces.

When releasing a new version that modifies the interface, add a new interface and implement both.  Make your objects implement both interfaces.

This will allow you to stagger rollouts and remain backward compatible.  You can deprecate and remove old interfaces at whatever time makes the most sense for your schedule.

Here's an example.  Note that I didn't think out the design of the services at all, except with respect to solving your specific problem:

```
namespace Version1
{
    public interface IOpenDefectService
    {
        void Submit(string title, string description, int severity);
        void Bump(int issueId);
    }
}

namespace Version2
{
    public interface IOpenDefectService
    {
        void Submit(string title, string description, int severity);

        // Removed Bump method - it was a bad idea

        // Added an optional priority field
        void Submit(string title, string description, int severity,
            int priority);

        // Added support for deleting 
        void Delete(int id);
    }
}

public class OpenDefectService : Version1.IOpenDefectService,
    Version2.IOpenDefectService
{
    // Still must support it until you no longer have any clients using it.
    // Here to support staggered rollouts
    [Obsolete("This method is deprecated.  Don't use it")]
    public void Bump(int issueId) { /* Still has implementation... */ }

    public void Submit(string title, string description,
        int severity) { /* ... */ }
    public void Submit(string title, string description,
        int severity, int priority) { /* ... */ }
    public void Delete(int id) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: I have not deployed any interface yet. Part of the question is just how much to support for the first interface (which i am pretty sure the basic set of operations may be enough). Why do i need to introduce a new interface instead of updating the existing one?

Comment: Also, can you given an example to illustrate how runtime and compile time behaviours differ.

Comment: This answer addresses: "In order to support more operations in the future". "I have not deployed any interface yet" - Then you don't need to introduce a new interface, or a new decorator.  Just change your interface :)

Comment: I meant - i am about to release this using the simplified interface that contains 2-3 operations, but would like to keep work to a minimum when updating this to support more operations in the next few months/years.

Comment: @liortal: Minimum work (if you can redeploy the whole thing at once) is to just edit your interface.  You don't need to remain backward compatible if you're your only consumer, and you replace the entirety of your app in one swoop.

Comment: I will not be the only consumer, though i would have access for updating all consumers. I would like to keep the "clients" of this interface in a working state, with no need to make code changes, while at the same time update the interface to support new features.

Comment: @liortal: If your adding a method, they have to change their code to use the new method.  Are you talking on a higher level architecturally than just a single class hierarchy?

Comment: Adding a new method doesn't FORCE people to use it, but it adds functionality that clients may be able to use. My concern is that adding methods/operations will not break already-deployed clients from working or force me to change any code except for the framework code.

Comment: @liortal: You can't edit an interface once it is published unless you want to break clients.  Which works fine if you're wiping out the clients.  "it adds the functionality that the clients may be able to use".  How do you propose they use it if they don't edit their code?  They gain nothing with the decorator over the multiple interfaces in that case.  I think we've got some sort of disconnect going on here :)  I can't stay up to chat but feel free to start the conversation and we can chat async.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5751/discussion-between-liortal-and-merlyn-morgan-graham)